# Congrats to Max Goodridge for reaching 1000 points!

Tags: discussion, congratulations

Please congratulate @MaxGoodridge for reaching what I consider the first great milestone! Good job young man! Keep up the hard work :D You've been asking a lot of great questions and assisting the site a bunch!

Comment: Already?  Definitely great questions.  Cool guy too.  Nice to have you around @MaxGoodridge   Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys! This is such a brilliant, friendly community and I am simply glad to be a part of it. I learn so much from you all! And thank you for all your patience and positivity when you are addressing my questions on here or in chat!

Congrats everyone else who has also reached a milestone recently!

Comment: Congrats Max! Keep up the good work.